# How can I do conditional validation in a Ruby on Rails Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a `study` that can have `participants`. I have a [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) where the user can add participants. It looks a bit like a table:

```
name | company | email OR mobile | timezone
name | company | email OR mobile | timezone
name | company | email OR mobile | timezone
```

By default, the screen has three fieldset rows, and the user can add more rows if needed. Each row is one participant.

I would like my `participant` model to validate only the rows that have been filled out, and ignore rows that are blank because even though we are showing three by default to the user, not all three are required fields.

Here's the relevant portion of `app/models/participants.rb`.

```
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :study

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :company, presence: true
  validates :time_zone, presence: true

  if :channel == 'sms'
    validates :mobile_number, presence: true
  elsif :channel == 'email'
    validates :email, presence: true
  end
end
```

In `participants_controller.rb` I have:

```
def index
  3.times { @study.participants.build } if @study.participants.length.zero?
end
```

The problem is that I get an error because simple_form thinks that all three fields are required, and not just the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default all inputs are required. When the form object includes
>   ActiveModel::Validations (which, for example, happens with Active
>   Record models), fields are required only when there is presence
>   validation. Otherwise, Simple Form will mark fields as optional. For
>   performance reasons, this detection is skipped on validations that
>   make use of conditional options, such as :if and :unless.
>
> And of course, the required property of any input can be overwritten
>   as needed:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, required: false %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Try to put all the inputs as **required: false**. That should allow skip simple_form validations and the data came into the controller and the model can be filtered or/and validated and every other things you want to do before persist.

In the model class you can use several ways of validations for example:

you also can use the **:if and :unless options** with a symbol corresponding to the name of a method that will get called right before validation happens. This is the most commonly used option.

for example

```
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :study

   validates :name, presence: true
   validates :company, presence: true
   validates :time_zone, presence: true
   validates :mobile_number, presence: true if: :channel_is_sms? 
   validates :email, presence: true if: :channel_is_email? 

  def channel_is_sms?
    channel == "sms"
  end

  def channel_is_email?
    channel == "email"
  end
end
```

or also you can use **custom validator** where you do all that you need validate. for example

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless record.channel == 'sms'
      ...
      ...  actions here
      ...
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

Comment: Thanks! To your first point, I tried to pass through `required: false` as a default for the form following the simple_form documentation, but couldn't get that to work. Putting `required: false` on each input did the trick.

Comment: I also found it was a bit cleaner to have only one method for checking whether it was sms in this case, and then using `unless` for the email validator. e.g. `if sms?` and `unless sms?` at the end of the mobile field and email field validator lines.

Answer (score 2):

Rails' validators accept conditions:

```
validates :mobile_number, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |p| p.study.channel == 'sms' }
validates :email,         presence: true, if: Proc.new { |p| p.study.channel == 'email' }
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain Proc.new? Can I not just say something like `if: self.channel == 'sms'` ?

Comment: Hmm, this isn't working, and I think I wasn't clear – studies have a channel, not the participant. I think your answer currently is looking for the participant.channel, hence the p.